# PHP - AJAX - is it possible to generate HTML using PHP and return that to AJAX to replace the contents of a <div>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am working on a web application where it allows you to post a simple comment to the database on a form submit, what I want to do is generate a new list of all comments written and use AJAX to replace a div where comments are to be stored, this to show the newest written comment after submitting it.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postCommentForm').submit(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("JS Submitted");

            function addCommentAJAX_call(commentTitleBox,commentBox,source_name,place_id,city_id)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url      : "funcsAJAX.php",
                    type     : "post",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data     : {
                                'commentTitleBox' : commentTitleBox,
                                'commentBox'      : commentBox ,
                                'source_name'     : source_name ,
                                'place_id'        : place_id ,
                                'city_id'         : city_id
                            },
                    success  : function(response)
                            {
                                console.log(response);
                                $('#g').html(response);
                            
                            },
                   
                });
            }

            var commentTitleBox = $('#commentTitleBox').val();
            var commentBox = $('#commentBox').val();
            var source_name = $('#source_name').val();
            var place_id = $('#place_id').val();
            var city_id = $('#city_id').val();

            addCommentAJAX_call(commentTitleBox,commentBox,source_name,place_id,city_id);   
        });
    });
```

This is the jQuery code I use to pull data from the form and post it to the webserver, note that the success part is unfinished as it never fired for me, #g is the div which contents I want to replace.

Next is the handler for the AJAX call

```
extract($_POST);



    #addCommentAJAX_call handler

    $user = 'user';
    $pass = 'pass';
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=twincities;charset=utf8',$user,$pass);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("<h3>connection to be failed, not surprising really heres why ".$e->getMessage());
    
    }
        
    addComment($db,$city_id,$place_id,$commentTitleBox,$commentBox,$source_name);

    $allComments = showCommentsForAJAX($db,$city_id,$place_id);
        

    $db->connection = null;

        
    echo json_encode($allComments);
```

This will create PDO object and then addComment() will add the comment to the database, it works fine with no issues.

showCommentsForAJAX() is the function I want to use that returns the comments from the database

```
function showCommentsForAJAX($db,$cityID,$placeID)
    {
        try
        {
            if($cityID && $placeID)
            {
                $query = "select * from comment where place_place_id = :place_place_id and city_city_woeid = :city_city_woeid"; 
                $queryVars = ['place_place_id' => $placeID,'city_city_woeid' => $cityID];
            }
            else if($cityID)
            {
                $query = "select * from comment where city_city_woeid = :city_city_woeid"; 
                $queryVars = ['city_city_woeid' => $cityID]; 
            }

            $query = $query." ORDER BY `timestamp` desc";
      
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($queryVars);

            $returnHTML = "";
            $returnHTML = $returnHTML . '<div id=comments>';
            while($comment = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                $returnHTML = $returnHTML . '<div id=commentIDis'.$comment['comment_id'].'>
                <h3>'.$comment['title'].'</h3>
                <br>
                <p>'.$comment['content'].'</p>
                <br>
                <p>-'.$comment['source_name'].'</p>
                <br>
                
                ';
                $returnHTML = $returnHTML . '</div>';
            }
            $returnHTML = $returnHTML . '</div>';

           
            return $returnHTML;
            
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            die("<h3> ROLLBACK something broke, not surprising really heres why ".$e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I want to based off the entries in the database, to build the comments' HTML and return that to AJAX, I am not sure how to encode the result for AJAX to understand it, and I believe that the logic for $returnHTML is incorrect and there is a better method of doing what I want but I am not sure how to achieve that, I have done a similar thing using Flask before where I used jinja templating to generate the HTML and successfully replace the contents of a div, but due to this university project I need to use PHP.

Suggestions to code layout are also very appreciated

Comment: `"is it possible to generate HTML using PHP"` - yes, absolutely!
`"I am not sure how to encode the result for AJAX to understand it"` - Just send back formatted HTML - no need to `json_encode` the html, the ajax callback is using `$('#g').html( response ) so plain HTML response is expected ( not a jquery expert by any means though )

Comment: Hi , change `echo json_encode($allComments);` to `echo $allComments;` .Also , remove `dataType : "json",` then see if you have any error inside browser console and what does `console.log(response)` shows.